# Cannot insert multiple elements in PriorityQueue

Tags: heapsort

I'm trying to implement a heap sorting algorithm.
My problem is when I try to insert Elements to my PriorityQueue, it only works for one element. When I add multiple elements to it, I get these errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Element cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:652)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:647)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:321)
at PQHeap.insert(PQHeap.java:47)
at PQHeap.main(PQHeap.java:17)
```

This is my Element class

```
public class Element {
public int key;
public Object data;

public Element(int i, Object o) {
    this.key = i;
    this.data = o;
}}
```

The interface:

```
    public interface PQ {
    public Element extractMin();
    public void insert(Element e);
}
```

And this is the class, which generates the heap. Note that the main class is located here just to debug with. When I only insert Element e, it works. But when I insert f aswell, it give's me the errors above.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PQHeap implements PQ{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PQHeap hq = new PQHeap(5);
        Element e = new Element(5, null);

        hq.insert(e);
        hq.insert(f);

        for(int in = 0; in<hq.pq.size();in++){
        System.out.println(hq.pq.remove());
        }


    }// end of main method

    public PriorityQueue<Element> pq;


    public PQHeap(int maxElms) {
        this.pq = new PriorityQueue<Element>(maxElms);
    }



    @Override
    public Element extractMin() {
        Element min = pq.remove();
        System.out.println(min.key);
        return min;

    }


    @Override
    public void insert(Element e) {
        this.pq.add(e);

    }
```

Comment: Java's `PriorityQueue` expects a class that implements `Comparable`. Otherwise, you have to provide a custom `Comparator` to the constructor call. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: That fixed the problem! thanks.